# Intuition behind $f(x)=x^n$ does not converge uniformly on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I would appreciate if someone could provide some intuition on why $f_n(x) =x^n$ does not converge uniformly on $(0,1)$.

I am comfortable with the fact that $f_n(x)=x^n$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1]$. The limit function is not continuous. It seemed to me that the only point that was causing the trouble is $x=1$. So I guessed that $f_n$ would converge on $(0,1)$.

However, that was not the case, since we can always choose $x = \epsilon^{1/n}$. Then we will have $|x^n|=|\epsilon|$. But it we move even further away from $1$, namely $(0,1-\delta)$, then it seems like we are good since $|x^n|<|(1-\delta)^n|\to0$

I can come up with the proof but it's a little bit counter intuitive to me :(

Comment: When you are strictly away from the $x=1$ then you do have uniform convergence. However, if you are arbitrarily close to $x=1$, then your family of functions can't be uniformly convergent because it always have values very close to $1$ for some $f_n$.

Comment: I don't understand your "However, ...".  $x^n$ does indeed converge to $0$ for any $x\in (0,1)$.  You can't "always choose $x = \epsilon^{1/n}$", because that's not a fixed $x$, it's dependent on $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How should I prove that $x^n$ does not converge uniformly on $(0,1)$ then?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Also, why cannot $x$ be dependent on $n$? I thought that's how you show not being uniformly convergent. Namely, it fails for some $x$.

Comment: When you ask whether it converges on $(0,1)$, you need $x$ to be fixed.  When you ask whether it converges uniformly, you can take $x$ dependent on $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition is that for $x \in (0,1)$, $x^n$ converges to $0$: higher and higher powers of $x$ get smaller and smaller, and eventually less than any $\epsilon > 0$.  But if $x$ is very close to $1$, it takes a very high power to make $x^n$ small, so the convergence is not uniform.

Answer (score 0):

$f_n(x)\geq \max(0,1+n(x-1))$ holds by convexity. For any $x\in(0,1)$,
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=0$$
hence the pointwise limit of $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\geq 1}$ is the zero function on $(0,1)$.
 Such limit cannot be a uniform limit, since
$$ \forall n\geq 1,\qquad\sup_{x\in(0,1)} \left|f_n(x)-0\right|\geq \frac{1}{2} $$
by the initial inequality, if you like.